# Cannot find file and folder $RECYCLE.BIN in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

I have recovered a deleted file `Episode2.wmv`. In recovery software it was showing it in folder `$RECYCLE.BIN\SOME-STRANGE-LONG-FOLDER-NAME\Episode2.wmv`. I recovered it on root `c:\` but I am unable to find this file or folder.

Just to check I again run recovery software and tried recovering that file again but it show me that file `Episode2.wmv` already exists.

I have searched for file and for folder but could not find it.

Where can I find folder `$RECYCLE.BIN` on `Windows 7` and why can't I see that file. I have also `show all hidden file and folders from folder option` but not luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$Recycle.Bin` isn't just a hidden folder, it's a protected system folder. To be able to see it, go to Folder Options -> View and uncheck the "Hide protected operating system files" option.

Answer (score 0):

Untick "Hide protected operating system files" under folder options and try again.